# Error using bind_rows with list of quantiles

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of quantiles in the output of `pull`, each element of the list is a named numeric vector  with the decile position.

```
tibble(norm=rnorm(1e3, 100, 1000), group=sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 1e3, TRUE)) %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise_at("norm", ~list(quantile(.x, seq(0,1,.1)))) %>% 
    pull(norm) %>%
    bind_rows()
```

But it generates the following error:

> Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names

I have no idea why i'm getting this error, since bind_rows seems to work nicely with similar examples. And the code works well with `rbind_list()`

the dplyr version been used is `0.7.4`.

**the desired output:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 11
#   `0%` `10%` `20%` `30%` `40%` `50%` `60%` `70%` `80%` `90%` `100%`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1  2.97  3.37  3.43  3.47  3.51  3.54  3.57  3.60  3.64  3.70   3.99
#2  2.88  3.21  3.30  3.35  3.40  3.44  3.48  3.52  3.57  3.64   3.84
#3  2.60  3.08  3.16  3.21  3.26  3.31  3.36  3.40  3.47  3.53   3.86
#4  2.13  2.60  2.67  2.73  2.79  2.87  2.93  2.99  3.08  3.20   3.41
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` and `purrr` we can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_at("norm", ~list(quantile(.x, seq(0,1,.1)))) %>% 
  pull(norm) %>% 
  map_df(bind_rows)
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 11
   `0%` `10%` `20%` `30%`  `40%`  `50%` `60%` `70%` `80%` `90%` `100%`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 -2834 -1228  -708  -473 -190     66.4   265   673  1011  1350   3123
2 -2971 - 889  -622  -330 - 69.6  120     417   657   936  1269   3126
3 -3368 -1207  -665  -356 -174     90.7   324   627   990  1426   2476
4 -3579 -1262  -769  -491 -227   - 17.8   211   508   831  1245   2806
```

Data:

```
df <- tibble(
  norm = rnorm(1e3, 100, 1000), 
  group = sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 1e3, TRUE)
)
```

Comment: No, i am really looking for it be organized by rows, and next to it i can add a column name with the group label.

Comment: I have updated my answer, let me know if this is what you're after

Comment: Thanks @tyluRp, it worked very well, but in my mind it still doesnt make sense bind_rows working inside the map, for me it would make sense if i had a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to handle the job. You need to have data frames when you use `bind_rows()`. So you want to create data frames based on the `norm` column in `summarise_at()`. You can create a column with rownames of each data frame. This info is percentile. Then, you use `bind_rows()`. You clean up column names and replace values in `Group`. I think there may be a more concise way to do the job. This is what I can do for you now.

```
mytib <- tibble(norm = rnorm(1e3, 100, 1000), 
                group = sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 1e3, TRUE))

group_by(mytib, group) %>% 
summarise_at("norm", ~list(quantile(.x, seq(0,1,.1)))) %>% 
pull(norm) %>%
lapply(as.data.frame) %>%
lapply(rownames_to_column) %>%
bind_rows(.id = "Group") %>%
setNames(c("Group", "Percentile", "Value")) %>%
mutate(Group = rep(sort(unique(mytib$group)), each = n() / n_distinct(Group)))
```

A part of the result is the blow.

```
   Group Percentile       Value
1      a         0% -2969.41031
2      a        10% -1100.39816
3      a        20%  -622.69348
4      a        30%  -423.08332
5      a        40%  -140.71709
6      a        50%    72.34586
7      a        60%   318.77128
8      a        70%   574.75911
9      a        80%   853.70942
10     a        90%  1405.57527
11     a       100%  3254.30424
12     b         0% -2443.18790
13     b        10% -1221.17822
14     b        20%  -822.14883
15     b        30%  -536.71329
16     b        40%  -152.42027
17     b        50%    56.48301
18     b        60%   234.95982
19     b        70%   418.50382
20     b        80%   706.30857
21     b        90%  1248.54743
22     b       100%  3501.81753
```